# I want to connect nginx and django on openshift

Tags: django, nginx, openshift

So I have an instance of nginx running on my openshift and another pod for a django app, the thing is I don't know how to connect both services. I'm able to access hte default url for nginx and the url for django. Both are working fine but I don't know how to connect both services. Is there a way to do it modifying the yaml of the services or the pods? I already try to build the container myself of nginx and is giving me permission issues,  so I'm using a version of nginx thats comes preloaded in openshift. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

To have access between pods you have to have [service](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html#services) created for every pod.
Then you can use service-name as DNS names to reach pods. If pods are placed in different projects you should additionally specify project name like *.*

Furthermore, there's environment variables for service discovery (see [service discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services))

Objects examples check in [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)